# Set Windows Error Reporting (WER) service to "disabled"?

Tags: windows-7, services, privacy, windows-services, patch

For non-ESU Windows 7 devices, is there any reason to have Windows Error Reporting (WER) service set to anything except "disabled"?

After all, those systems will not be receiving any more updates from Microsoft, and I'm not aware of Microsoft sharing Windows Error Reporting data with third-party patch developers.

Answer (score 1):

One main point of WER reporting is to fix bugs in the operating system. Windows 7 will no longer be fixed, so yes, if you wish to disable it, you can.

Since software for Windows 7 is getting old, I am pretty sure error reporting applies mostly to newer versions.

Comment: Thanks John.  I'm having a little challenge understanding your second paragraph.  Can you reword it?

Comment: I did re-word and I trust that helps.

Comment: Thanks John! Are you saying that software that runs on Windows 7 (not talking about the actual OS itself) is often older versions, and therefore WER would not apply?

Comment: Yes, there will be some software that will cross OS boundaries and if such software causes issues, vendors will probably be made aware. If software is obsolete, then no.

Comment: Microsoft still collects data to solve problems and integrate into ESU patches.